# Parsing Xhtml strict documents with RestFixture

Tags: rest, fitnesse, fixture

I have an xpath like 
//xhtml:title[text()='Page Title']

and am getting an error from RestFixture that reads

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot extract xpath '//xhtml:title[text='Page Title']' from the document

When I remove the 

from the document and the xhtml namespace from the xpath string it works fine.

When I do an xpath query with 4xpath on the command line it does not work unless I specify the --namespace=xhtml=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml switch and include the namespace specifier in the xpath string.

I guess the question is, is there anyway to specify the namespace with RestFixture or is there any black magic that needs to be done to get xpath to work with RestFixture on a xhtml strict document?

Answer (score 1):

I have added support for namespaces in the latest version of the RestFixture. Check it out here: http://smartrics.blogspot.com/2011/01/restfixture-with-namespaces-support.html